# Why does Attachment.Add generate a Type Mismatch error?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to add an attachment to my Outlook email but must be missing something simple. I have been researching but no come across a way around it just yet.

My Code:

```
With objEmail
    .To = email
    .From = strFrom
    .CC = strCC
    .Subject = "A New Deli Order has been Received"
    .textbody = "Please find attached a new deli order"
    .Attachments.Add ("C:\123.pdf")

With .Configuration.Fields
        .Item(strItem & "sendusing") = 2
        .Item(strItem & "smtpserver") = "mailhost"
        .Item(strItem & "smtpserverport") = 25
        .Update

    End With
    .Send
End With
```

I thought the simple below line would work

> .Attachment

Do I need DIM anything? If so as what?

**The error received:**

> Type Mismatch

Comment: Best practise is to use Option Explicit. That means you should DIM everything.

Comment: Does `.Attachments.Add "C:\123.pdf"` work?

Comment: What is objEmail? Please show, how you create it

Comment: MailItem object does not expose a property called "From"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this version.

```
Sub Mail_ActiveSheet()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            'You use Excel 97-2003
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            'You use Excel 2007-2016
            Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
            Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If .HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
        End If
    End With

    '    'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
    '    With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    '        .Cells.Copy
    '        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    '        .Cells(1).Select
    '    End With
    '    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Part of " & Sourcewb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Destwb
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .to = "ron@debruin.nl"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
            .Body = "Hi there"
            .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Send   'or use .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    'Delete the file you have send
    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail2.htm

You will find lots of useful Excel/Outlook scripts at the link below.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm